# How should I get 'This is my name ' from multiple spans in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <div id='item1'>
    <span>This is my name</span>
    <span> This is my nickname</span>
```

Need JS code to fetch a specific span

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
document.getElementById("item1").children[0];
```

To get the first child of your div (ie the first span) and then use `.textContent` on this node to get "This is my name"

See working example below:

```js
const firstChild = document.getElementById("item1").children[0];
console.log(firstChild.textContent);
```

```html
<div id='item1'>
  <span>This is my name</span>
  <span> This is my nickname</span>
</div>
```

Or, if you wish to use jQuery:

```js
const firstChild = $("#item1").children().eq(0);
console.log($(firstChild).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='item1'>
  <span>This is my name</span>
  <span> This is my nickname</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `<span> This is my nickname</span>
<span>This is my name</span>` when mark up is like this this is wrong

Answer (score 0):

1. Use selector `:contains()` to select the span which contains the text `This is my name`

```js
$("span:contains(This is my name)").css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>This is my name</span>
<span> This is my nickname</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` with `eq` like below.

```js
var item1 = $('#item1').find('span').eq(0).text();
var item2 = $('#item1').find('span').eq(1).text();
console.log(item1);
console.log(item2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='item1'>
  <span>This is my name</span>
  <span> This is my nickname</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can use

```
$('#item1 > span:first-child').text()
```

```js
var text = $('#item1 > span:first-child').text();
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='item1'>
  <span>This is my name</span>
  <span> This is my nickname</span>
</div>
```